# Ubuntu taking about 5 minutes to Boot!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, 18.04, user-space

Please suggest if you have some experience with what can I do to decrease boot time. What is the reason for the userspace taking so long?

```
$ sudo systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 3.395s (firmware) + 14.332s (loader) + 38.152s (kernel) 
+ 3min 3.432s (userspace) = 3min 59.313s
graphical.target reached after 2min 3.881s in userspace
```

- [System Configuration](https://gist.github.com/Agarwal-Nikhil/1432ec0565120af69a9110002d19f1f0)
- [dmesg -T](https://gist.github.com/Agarwal-Nikhil/14127383ab1b7573cc2d9752c3a4d951)
- [systemd-analyze blame](https://gist.github.com/Agarwal-Nikhil/de637e4b6f46ed11d6699190b374de75)

Comment: Looks like you ran a blame report. Did you look up the largest culprits? What did you find?

Comment: What's behind the three loop devices and what kind of storage device is behind `/dev/sda7`, all of which take upwards of 10s to mount, which is about two orders of magnitude more than it should take. Did you check them for hardware errors? Drives tend to become slow when they degrade due to age or manufacturing errors. I don't know about Plymouth; that could just be to display something pretty until all the other boot tasks are finished, which you can test by decreasing the time spent on other things.

Comment: I just updated the whole system, grub too. It took 6 mins to boot, it seems to take a huge long time scanning for LVM partitions... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196874/18-04-grub-takes-about-6-minutes-to-boot-lvm-problem

Answer (score 0):

you can try to change timeout to 0 in

> sudo nano /etc/default/grub

then ctrl+o to save changes, "Enter", and finally ctrl+x to exit

if above command does not work [this might help you](https://elinux.org/Boot-up_Time_Reduction_Howto)

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. The solution you are recommending will definetly not reduce boot time significantly in the case at hand.