# 18.04, grub takes about 6 minutes to boot, problem: `systemd-udevd 'SomeDevice' is taking a long time`

Tags: 18.04, grub2, systemd, lvm, udev

after a whole system update (that I try to avoid usually), I thought I was unable to boot, but this time I decided to wait more.

so after exactly 6m05s (everytime is that precise delay) it finally completes booting :(

just before the update it was very fast, so I exclude any hardware problem.

**[you may jump to read the last update currently 2019-12-25]**

other questions I found arent related to LVM, but this case seems to be as the last failure message is about scanning for LVM:

[image]
[image]
[image]

yes, initially there is some stuff about irq and ACPI, I tried adding this but didnt help `acpi=strict`, so my guess is that it is a LVM problem.

I found some stuff on the log that may help (omitting "dups"):

```
#happens 5 times
syslog.1:Dec 18 18:52:29 MyHostName lvm[803]:   WARNING: lvmetad is being updated, retrying (setup) for 10 more seconds.

syslog.1:Dec 18 18:52:29 MyHostName systemd[1]: Created slice system-lvm2\x2dpvscan.slice.

# happens 20 times, each for a different device
syslog.1:Dec 18 18:52:29 MyHostName lvm[814]:   WARNING: lvmetad is being updated, retrying (setup) for 10 more seconds.
syslog.1:Dec 18 18:52:29 MyHostName systemd[1]: Starting LVM2 PV scan on device 8:31...

syslog.1:Dec 18 18:52:29 MyHostName systemd[1]: Started Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.

syslog.1:Dec 18 18:52:29 MyHostName kernel: [    2.460879] random: lvm: uninitialized urandom read (4 bytes read)

#logs like this happened for each device also
syslog.1:Dec 18 18:52:29 MyHostName lvm[625]:   4 logical volume(s) in volume group "MyLvmGroupName" monitored
syslog.1:Dec 18 18:52:29 MyHostName lvm[911]:   4 logical volume(s) in volume group "MyLvmGroupName" now active
```

The above, despite saying "for 10 more seconds" it all seems to happen on the same second at "Dec 18 18:52:29" what doesnt make much sense to me, it was many threads? anyway...

obs.: grub v 2.02-2ubuntu8.14

I check the boot time with `sudo systemd-analyze time`

After this latest update, when I turn on the computer, it usually "freezes" on the 1st boot (just after the boot choice is made (normal or advanced boot etc)), but I can ctrl+alt+del. After this it goes to this slowed boot problem...

---

**19/Dec/2019** Today I saw something interesting +- like this:
`/dev/mapper/MyLVMGroupName: clean` I couldnt take a photo, was too fast and I cant find it anywhere at /var/log (ubuntu has no boot log???) well... it appeared to me that a `fsck` was being run (has been being run) everytime and it is taking 6min to complete? Obs.: yesterday I did a normal shutdown, so I think it should be clean already, no need for fsck...
**Another** thing about this: the desktop red led (that shows us if is happening some kind of hard drive I/O) doesnt blink a single time during that 6m delay, before showing fsck clean message, so... it is not spending time reading/writing. So what is happening? could be some kind of timeout, but why it says nothing about it?

there is nothing at `systemd-analyze blame` that spent more than 6 seconds also.

---

**2019-12-25**: to the `linux` grub command, I added `debug --verbose` and got this!
after 60s waiting:
`systemd-udevd 'SomeDevicePartition' is taking a long time`
after more 120s:
`systemd-udevd 'SomeDevicePartition' killed`
they happen at +- : 60s, 180s, 240s, 365s
so a total of 6minutes!!!
**I wonder if udevd killing timeout could be lowered to may be 10s and do not retry? (using some config in the grub entry)**

---

My last guess is that all this is just some annoying bug :(

**so, how I can fix this?**

Can I hint grub to fastly detect LVM stuff?

linked: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559929/very-slow-boot-6m-where-udevadm-stores-its-config/559979#559979

Comment: What happens when you boot into a previous kernel?

Comment: I tried with 4 previous kernels on advanced boot options and had the same problem, I think the problem is not a kernel specific thing then?

Comment: I am wondering if I could use `udevadm --timeout=10` (the default says 120s but what I got is 60s) but the problem is that it is about events in general, not specifically to the hard drive detection...

Answer (score 0):

used a workaround to solve this problem:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559929/very-slow-boot-6m-how-to-force-change-systemd-udevd-timeout-to-5s/559979#comment1041816_559979

```
linux /vmlinuz-4.15.0-72-generic \
 udev.event-timeout=5 \
 root=/dev/mapper/MyLvmGroupName ro nosplash \
 $vt_handoff debug --verbose
```

As I didnt do a lot of tests to be 100% sure:
I think both `debug` and `--verbose` let me know what was happening.
I think `udev.event-timeout=5` has to be before `root=` param.
I am sure `rd.udev.event-timeout=5` was ignored.

Comment: after setting that entry to default, I found out also that the first time it boots (if I dont ctrl+alt+del) it will boot normally but wont output anything until login screen, so it will look like frozen but isnt!