# 18.04 grub freezes when reaching initrd on first boot

Tags: grub2, freeze, initrd

Happens ALWAYS, just after I turn on the desktop pc, and only once.

Then I have to soft reboot (ctrl+alt+del) (instead of use the desktop reset button).

After that soft reboot, it boots normally.

It is not a total freeze that happens when running exactly the line of `initrd`, as I can still use the keyboard to reboot.

I have no idea what to do... All these troubles ([18.04, grub takes about 6 minutes to boot, problem: `systemd-udevd 'SomeDevice' is taking a long time`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196874/18-04-grub-takes-about-6-minutes-to-boot-problem-systemd-udevd-somedevice)) begun after I whole updated the OS, so I am scared of doing it again any soon, but I think I will have to as soon any related updates are available.

Any tip?

I dont feel this is a good question anyway... but I also dont know how to make it more answerable...

I just dont know what to do as when initrd should start, it just does nothing! and provides no log either!

`initrd` should always be verbose or in debug mode (like we can do with the `linux debug --verbose` command.

I think `initrd`, `linux` and everything else related to **boot** should always be verbose and debug as much as possible, w/o we having to manually set these things.

Cleaner boot log on linux makes not sense to me IMHO (does it even save a log at all? I can never find boot entries on /var/log ...)

---

Edit20200114 - `initrd` is a simple grub command:
https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/redhat/enterprise3/rhel-rg-en-3/s1-grub-commands.html

so I guess I need to wait for a grub update and hope it gets fixed, or downgrade grub...

---

Edit 20200131 -
I think this is related, but is from 2013! https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1154917
I made other tests also like `initrd _IntendedToFail_` just before the real one, it just fails and asks to "press a key to continue" and freezes just after, working only after ctrl+alt+del or reset button (on the 2nd boot).

Comment: During a cold boot edit kernel parameters (edit mode in grub2) erase any like `splash` or `quiet` and add instead  `debug=vc` this will print debug info to your virtual console, during boot. may you see something helpful.

Comment: @nobody thx! will take note and edit the entry on next boot!

Comment: didnt work (like in nothing different happened). Btw, I think this is related but is from 2013 :( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1154917